# How to set x axis tick width and label

Tags: python, seaborn

The x axis is year-month of date of two years. Hence 24 values. Because the relplot function only allows numeric type for x and y axis. So the x axis is all clustered to two ends since 201801 to 201912 is not equally spaced. How I could make it equally spaced with correct label like this: 201801,201802....201912. (24 date values)

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
palette = dict(zip(rel['Sub-Category'].unique(),
                   sns.color_palette("rocket_r", 17)))
r=sns.relplot(x='YearMonth', y="Profit",
            hue="Sub-Category", col="Category",
            #size="Year", size_order=["2019", "2018"], 
            palette=palette,
            height=5, aspect=.7, facet_kws=dict(sharex=True),
            kind="line", legend="full", data=rel)
r.set(yticks=[i for i in range(int(min(rel['Profit'])), int(max(rel['Profit'])) + 50, 500)],
     xticks=[i for i in rel.YearMonth.unique()])
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOGUs.png)

Comment: is your `YearMonth` column a datetime? If not you could convert it with `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: @baccandr Ya, YearMonth column was used as group by column from previous df. It was originally extracted using dt.to_period('M') from a string date column.

Comment: Well I guess that's the problem, you should use a datetime not a period. `relplot` just works fine when dealing with datetimes.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your `rel` dataframe?

Comment: @Let'stry Here is a sample of `rel` dataframe.   `pd.DataFrame({'YearMonth': ['2018-01','2018-01','2018-02'],'Category':['Clothing','Furniture','Clothing'], 'Sub-Category':['Henkerchief','Table','Skirt'],'Profit':[16,40,110]})`

Answer (score 2):

As described in the comments you just have to convert your `YearMonth` column into a datetime:

```
# Input data
df = pd.DataFrame({'YearMonth': ['2018-01','2018-01','2018-02','2018-04','2018-03','2018-05'],
                   'Category':['Clothing','Furniture','Clothing','Clothing','Furniture','Clothing'], 
                   'Sub-Category':['Henkerchief','Table','Skirt','Henkerchief','Table','Skirt'],
                   'Profit':[16,40,110,33,44,55]})

# Create datetime column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'], format = '%Y-%m')

# Plot
sns.set(style="ticks")
palette = dict(zip(df['Sub-Category'].unique(),
                   sns.color_palette("rocket_r", 17)))
r=sns.relplot(x='date', y="Profit",
            hue="Sub-Category", col="Category",
            palette=palette,
            height=5, aspect=.7, facet_kws=dict(sharex=True),
            kind="line", legend="full", data=df)

# Adjust xticks
xticks = pd.date_range(start='2017-12',end='2018-05',
                       freq='MS',closed='right')
r.set(xticks=xticks)
```

This is the output figure:
[image]

**Update:**
If you want to rotate the xtick labels you can use:

```
for ax in r.axes.ravel():
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

Comment: When I run `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'], format = '%Y-%m')`, it returns , TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: I changed the column type in the previous df and now it works. But due to multiple year-month periods (24) and multiple subcategory (17), the label on x axis is not showing and the legend on the right is cut off half. How I could fit it better? Thanks.

Comment: @flyunicorn good that is working. to make the xaxis more readable there are several options, you can rotate the tick labels to have them vertical, you can reduce the number of ticks (simply change the frequency and use 3/4 months instead of one) or change the format to display only the month and the year. You need to try and see what works best for you...

Comment: Thanks a lot! One small question, how to set the rotation of xaxis inside the r.set()? My previous experience was setting inside r.set_xticklabels()?

Comment: @flyunicorn I updated the answer with a suggestion that shows how to rotate the xtick labels, I hope this helps.